# When creating Product Flavors in Gradle in Android Studio, how is the main module used?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-productflavors

I see that the Main module is automatically created when you create new product flavors in Android.  Is it possible to rename Main or must it be named Main?

Also, if you are only supposed to put code that differs from Main in the respective flavor folders, is it possible for Main to be completely empty?

Comment: "Is it possible to rename Main or must it be named Main?" -- AFAIK, `main` must remain named `main`. "is it possible for Main to be completely empty?" -- in theory, yes. In practice, if the flavors have nothing to do with one another, they should be separate modules or projects, IMHO. And, since I haven't tried this, I can't rule out some hiccups (e.g., build tools choking because `main` lacks an `AndroidManifest.xml` file or some such).

Comment: You can leave main blank, but its purpose is to keep files and resources common to your other flavors. For instance, Let's say your app icon can be  the same for both of your flavors, or different; in that case you could only replace your icon in one of your flavors, then, main and your other flavor will share the same icon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does not make much sense to leave your main flavor empty. If you want two flavors that differ in all files, just create a new project or module. You shouldn't rename main as most of the toolchain relies on the main flavor beeing called "main".
If you want an anser for your specific use case, please describe your use case!